# Do Events support profile "Redirect URL"?

Tags: civievent, profile, redirect

I set up a test event with a profile that had it's Redirect URL set. Upon registration, I was forwarded to the event confirmation screen instead of the profile's redirect URL. Do redirect URL's not work with Events?

Comment: i think a Profile redirect url only works with standalone Profiles as Event and Contributions have their own workflow

Comment: Yup, that's just for when you use it as a stand-alone. I think you may have to use the Webform CiviCRM integration (assuming you're using Drupal) to be able to do that.